# How to Update Adapter in another View

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

**This is what I have:**

Step 1.  There is a `ListView` that shows items a user can rate.  It is a `Fragment`.  Any item that has already been rated is made bold.

Step 2.  If user clicks on unrated item, it keeps the current list in the backstack and opens up new `Fragment`; on new `Fragment` they can now rate item.

**This is what I need:**

Step 3.  Once they hit back button, *I want the list item to now be bold to reflect change.*

If this wasn't a `Fragment`, I think `startActivityForResult()` would be the answer; but not sure how to do this with current (`Fragment`) setup?

Supplemental:  The `ListView` has an `adapter` of `ArrayList<Review>`.  Of course, each row has properties in the `Review` object.  One property is a pram called `wasRated` which is either `0` or `1`; if this param is 1, it means the user rated the item, the list row is made bold to reflect this.  This is what I want made dynamic.

Comment: So what you want to do is re-render the list in `Fragment 1` when `Fragment 2` closes? Have I understood the questions?

Comment: @NeilTownsend  Bascially yes;  I'd like to just update the row if possible, not reset the `listview` so the user has to scroll back down.

Comment: Wouldn't adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() do the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Creating event callbacks to the activity` section of the [Android developer page on Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) suggests that it is relatively easy to create callbacks from a `Fragment` to the holding `Activity`.

More generally, you can determine the `Activity` from the `Fragment`. Assuming:

1. you have an activity `MyTopNotchActivity` which starts both fragments
2. there is a method `needToReRender()` in the Activity which triggers rerendering

In Fragment 2:

```
MyTopNotchActivity activity = (MyTopNotchActivity) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);
activity.needToReRender();
```

The Activity can then tell `Fragment` 1 to rerender the list. Obviously you can improve `needToReRender` to receive information about precisely what needs rerendering.

Caveat: If the fragments are created by different activities this won't work.

Comment: Yes, they are both under the same `FragmentActivity`; so I see what you are saying...  let me give this a try

Comment: So I understand how to call a callback method from Fragment #2 .  But once I am in the Callback Method, it has to immediately call a method in Fragment #1 to make the list row change; in all my testing, I can't seem to make changes to Fragment #1 while Fragment #2 is active (and literally on top of).

Comment: Perhaps you need to set a flag in Fragment 1 which is detected in `onResume` in Fragment 1 so that when it acquires the screen it will rerender?

Comment: That makes senese;  so when you say re-render, is the best way maybe invalidating the whole `ListView` and refreshing?   Or just making the single change to the one row?

Comment: I would do whichever was easiest first to confirm that it worked, and then optimise once I had it working

Comment: Well I set a `boolean` flag in the `Fragment` 1 `onResume` - nothing.  Suppose to see a `Toast` when the variable changed to true in Fragment #2.  It was a global var boolean that I used in a Class that `extends Application`.  Not sure if `onResume` is even being called since the `Activity` isn't going away during any of this.

Comment: So if you put a Log line in `Fragment`1 `onResume` does it show in the logcat? If not, then the callback in the `Activity` will have to call the method in `Fragment`1 to update the Views in the list and the probably also `invalidate` the top `View`.

Comment: I got it working;  I went ahead and tried the Callback method like you said and it works great!  Not sure why it failed me the first time.